# MySQL update zero columns

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update zero columns in a MySQL update query?

I'd like to utilise the automatic updating of the timestamp column when this particular row is selected. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: means, you want to update timestamp whenever a record is selected by some other query? Am i right?

Comment: You want to update timestamp column and you still want to update zero columns? Its bit confusing question. Can you please provide more details about table structure? Also if you have zero columns to update, dont fire the SQL query. Dont you think that should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try something like :

```
UPDATE myTable SET someField = someField WHERE id = myId
```

So the data values won't move, and the automatic timestamp will be updated.

As said by GaryG, you may also update the timestamp directly.

Answer (score 2):

So you want your update query to only update the timestamp column?  Just update it yourself instead of relying on the automatic update:

```
UPDATE mytable SET tscolumn = NOW() WHERE ...
```